# Maven passing multiple values to a build parameter

Tags: maven, jenkins

We are invoking pom.xml from Jenkins. I have a Parameter 'ProjectName' which is of type extended choice. When we trigger build it contains multiple values. For e.g. **"GlobalVariable DBInvocations ErrorHandling"** etc. Here, delimiter is white space. When I invoke below maven command :

```
mvn -f pom.xml clean package -PcreateDist -Dtarget.project=%ProjectName%
```

I get Error :

```
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "DBInvocations". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException: Unknown lifecycle phase "DBInvocations". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateLifecycleMappings(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:246)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:96)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

Please let me know how can I pass multiple values to ProjectName parameter.

Parameter config is as shown in below screenshot.[image: Parameter Configuration]

Thanks,
Ranjeet

Comment: can you show the log of the failures , and the full config of the parameter ?

Comment: Edited question to add debug logs and attached screenshot for param config.

Comment: can you add **-X** to the MVN command PLS upload the console output ? , I want to see the MVN command

Comment: @MorLajb I already have updated question with console output after adding -X to MVN command. MVN command is :                                                                  `mvn -f pom.xml clean package -PcreateDist -Dtarget.project=GlobalVariable DBInvocations ErrorHandling`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally changed maven command as shown below :

```
mvn -f pom.xml clean package -PcreateDist "-Dtarget.project=%ProjectName%"
```

Now maven script invokes multiple ant targets mentioned in ProjectName parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should add **"** to the mvn command

```
-Dtarget.project="GlobalVariable DBInvocations ErrorHandling"
```